# express.js handlebars, get static files directory keep changes according to url

Tags: express, handlebars.js

I am new to express. Basically my question is very simple.
I want to serve files like /css javascript from one public directory..

layout.hbs

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body> 
      {{{body}}}
    </body>
  </html>
```

router.js --> I have three route that point to one index.hbs

```
router.get("/", function(req,res){
   res.render("index.hbs");
})
router.get("/articles", function(req,res){
   res.render("index.hbs");
})
router.get("/articles/show/:id", function(req,res){
   res.render("index.hbs");
})
```

Now the problem is when I run this address:

```
 curl "http://localhost:3000/"

      http://localhost:3000/js/app
      http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
----------------------------------------------
    curl "http://localhost:3000/articles"

      http://localhost:3000/articles/js/app
      http://localhost:3000/articles/css/style.css
----------------------------------------------
    curl "http://localhost:3000/show/1"

      http://localhost:3000/show/1/js/app
      http://localhost:3000/show/1/css/style.css
```

notice that the /css and /js path keep changing in accordance to UrlRequest. How to prevent this from happening?

I am using express and handlebars, and have already set my static file

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public');
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should specify the URLs to your JS and CSS as absolute URLs in your template: instead of `css/style.css`, use `/css/style.css`.

The first means "use this path **relative to this page** to browsers (and curl), the second "use this path **relative to the host** - which is what you want.

Comment: I see, it makes sense..  I think I get what you mean, perhaps I can  res.render("index.hbs", {css: __dirname+/path })  But that means I have to attach it all over the routes.. is there any simpler way? I mean even an <a> to other pages will always relative to this page.

Comment: Like I wrote - just add a leading `/` to your paths - this will mean they will always be relative to the host. For example '/css/style.css' will always mean 'http://localhost:3000/css/style.css' when your server is running on localhost, regardless of the URL of the actual page.